# How do I temporarily turn off AVG Antivirus?

Tags: windows, avg-antivirus

I run AVG Antivirus (version 8.5, I believe). Now I want to install "Dragon Naturally Speaking", a speech recognition software. During installation I'm told that I need to temporarily disable my antivirus. How do I temporarily disable it?

Comment: I suggest you attempt to install it without disabling your antivirus first, then if that fails you disable it and try again.

Comment: I will try that. But if it doesn't work then how do I turn AVG Antivirus off and back on?

Answer (score 4):

As @Eroen already said, this might not be necessary.

Most programs install just fine with the  antivirus enabled. If they don't, either the installer or the antivirus is poorly written.

From [Disabling AVG temporarily | FAQ | AVG Worldwide](http://www.avg.com/ww-en/faq.num-3857):

> The AVG software protects your computer on multiple levels. **In case you need to disable all AVG components at once** please follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Open the AVG Program.
> 2. On the **Tools** menu, click **Advanced settings**.
> 3. Click **Temporarily disable AVG protection** in the menu on the left side.
> 4. Select the **Temporarily disable AVG protection** check box, and then click **OK**.
> 5. Choose how long you want the protection to be disabled and whether to disable the Firewall as well, and then click **Disable real-time protection**.

Since you only disable it temporarily, there is no need to manually enable it afterwards. It will do so automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. Control Panel>Administrative Tools>System Configuration
2. Click on the Startup tab
3. Uncheck AVG
4. Click restart
5. do what you need to
6. repeat 1&2
7. recheck AVG, click restart again