# Temporarily Disable AVG Antivirus

Tags: internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I temporarily turn off AVG Antivirus?](https://superuser.com/questions/414471/how-do-i-temporarily-turn-off-avg-antivirus)

I want to install Dragon Naturally Speaking, Speech Recognition Software. It says I have to diable my Antivirus before I can install Dragon Naturally Speaking. How do I temporarily disable it and then turn it back on?

Comment: Donna Bergen, you already have a question active with this topic at http://superuser.com/questions/414471/how-do-i-temporarily-turn-off-avg-antivirus , posted just minutes ago. Please wait for an answer there.

Comment: it's a duplicate

Comment: Sorry Alexander Truemper

Answer (score 0):

Open AVG anti-virus. Click tools and then choose advanced settings. Then you will find an option to disable anti-virus temporarily.